# How to encode a dataset having multiple datatypes?

Tags: python-3.x, dataframe, scikit-learn, sklearn-pandas, label-encoding

I have a dataset like:

```py
e = pd.DataFrame({
    'col1': ['A', 'A', 'B', 'W', 'F', 'C'],
    'col2': [2, 1, 9, 8, 7, 4],
    'col3': [0, 1, 9, 4, 2, 3],
    'col4': ['a', 'B', 'c', 'D', 'e', 'F']
})
```

Here I encoded the data using `sklearn.preprocessing.LabelEncoder`. By the following lines of code:

```py
x = list(e.columns)
# Import label encoder 
from sklearn import preprocessing 
  
# label_encoder object knows how to understand word labels. 
label_encoder = preprocessing.LabelEncoder() 
for i in x:  
# Encode labels in column 'species'. 
    e[i] = label_encoder.fit_transform(e[i])
print(e)
```

But this is encoding even the numeric datapoint of `int` type, which is not required.

Encoded dataset :

```
col1  col2  col3  col4
0     0     1     0     3
1     0     0     1     0
2     1     5     5     4
3     4     4     4     1
4     3     3     2     5
5     2     2     3     2
```

How can I rectify this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One really simple possibility would be to only encode columns with string values.  E.g., tweaking your code to be:

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn import preprocessing 


e = pd.DataFrame({
    'col1': ['A', 'A', 'B', 'W', 'F', 'C'],
    'col2': [2, 1, 9, 8, 7, 4],
    'col3': [0, 1, 9, 4, 2, 3],
    'col4': ['a', 'B', 'c', 'D', 'e', 'F']
})


label_encoder = preprocessing.LabelEncoder() 
for col in e.columns:  
    if e[col].dtype == 'O':
        e[col] = label_encoder.fit_transform(e[col])

print(e)
```

or better yet:

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn import preprocessing 


def encode_labels(ser):
    if ser.dtype == 'O':
        return label_encoder.fit_transform(ser)
    else:
        return ser


label_encoder = preprocessing.LabelEncoder() 
e = pd.DataFrame({
    'col1': ['A', 'A', 'B', 'W', 'F', 'C'],
    'col2': [2, 1, 9, 8, 7, 4],
    'col3': [0, 1, 9, 4, 2, 3],
    'col4': ['a', 'B', 'c', 'D', 'e', 'F']
})


e_encoded = e.apply(encode_labels)
print(e_encoded)
```

Answer (score 2):

Filtering, and adapting your preprocessing to column types is the right idea, and the most efficient way of making it is with pandas pipeline.

```
from sklearn.compose import ColumnTransformer
from sklearn.compose import make_column_selector
from sklearn.preprocecssing import LabelEncoder, StandardScaler
```

### Example 1: applying a transformer depending on the column name

```
my_transformer1 = ColumnTransformer(
                     [
                         ('transform_name_for_col1', LabelEncoder(), 'col1'),
                         ('transformer_name_for_col2_and_col3', StandardScaler(), ['col2', 'col3'])
                     ]
                 )
```

### Example 2: applying a transformer depending on column type

```
my_transformer2 = ColumnTransformer(
                     [
                         ('transform_name_categories', LabelEncoder(), make_column_selector(dtype_include=object)),
                         ('transformer_name_for_numerical', StandardScaler(), make_column_selector(dtype_include=np.number))
                     ]
                 )
```

Obviously, replace LabelEncoder and StandardScaler by the transformer of your choice, including a custom one:

```
class MyCustomTransformer(BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin):
    def __init__(self):
        # do something
    
    def fit(self, X, y = None):
        # do something
        return self

    def transform(self, X, y = None):
        # do something
        # return something transformed
```

To go further, I recommend using scikit-learn Pipeline to combine different preprocessing depending on column and/or column type (which will be far more flexible).

See class details here:

- https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.compose.make_column_selector.html
- https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.compose.ColumnTransformer.html
- https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.pipeline.Pipeline.html

Comment: Thanks a lot for your such a descriptive answer! I will study this.